# GAE Golang Gorilla mux - 404 page not found

Tags: google-app-engine, go, mux

I've got some problems to use gorilla mux within GAE.

When I try it, I've '404 page not found'. The rootHandler function is not called ( no traces generated)

Below is part of my code, any ideas?

thk in advance

```
...
    func init() {
     r := mux.NewRouter()
     r.HandleFunc("/",rootHandler)
    }
    func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     var functionName = "rootHandler"
     c := appengine.NewContext(r)
     c.Infof(functionName+"-start")
     defer c.Infof(functionName+"-end")
...
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to route requests to your mux router. `http` package has `DefaultServeMux` which is used by AppEngine, but `mux` does not. (and it's not registering its routes with `net/http` by itself)

That is, all you have to do, is register your `mux` router with `net/http`:

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/articles", ArticlesHandler)
    http.Handle("/", r)
}
```

(straight from the docs)

Important part here is `http.Handle("/", r)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass the router as the second argument to `ListenAndServe` since it implements the `http.Handler` interface.

```golang
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router) // pass the router here
```