# How to properly serve a single static file with Gorilla mux?

Tags: http, go, static, gorilla

I had a look a this question [Serving static content with a root URL with the Gorilla toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834278/serving-static-content-with-a-root-url-with-the-gorilla-toolkit) and used the answer from there successfully.

I, though, want to declare explicitly which file I want to serve as static, for development purposes, like this:

```
router.PathPrefix("/style.css").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("/usr/local/myproject/style.css")))
```

Which worked as expected too.

Now, I wonder, if it's a correct way to serve a single explicitly defined file or should I do it differently?

Comment: What response you get when you access something like `<url>/style.css/abc` ?

Comment: I guess rather using `PathPrefix` you should use `Path` router

Comment: To serve a single file, a lighter / faster alternative is `http.ServeFile()`. See this answer for details: [Include js file in Go template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899675/include-js-file-in-go-template/28899786#28899786).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `http.ServeFile()` function directly:

```
http.ServeFile(w, r, "/usr/local/myproject/style.css")
```